# UITableView hide sectionindex but retain sections

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

We'd like to implement our own section index UI for UITableView.

It's clearly possible, since the contacts app does it on iPad. Is there a way of legally hiding the current section index?  (I can get to the undocumented _index UIView but that's not going to cut it with Apple I suspect)

Answer (score 14):

That answer helps.

The trick here is to have

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
```

return nil, while keeping implementations for the other section based data source methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

That seems to convince the tableview not to display a section index, but still allow navigation by index.

Answer (score 1):

Does the answer to this question help?:

[Customizing Section indexes in UITableView in iphone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643400/customizing-section-indexes-in-uitableview-in-iphone-application)