# Customizing Section indexes in UITableView in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

- Does any one have tried to customize default section index displayed in UITableView.
- I want to modify the appearance of UITableView SectionIndex.
- Is it possible to customize it ?
- Is there any delegate methods available for this ?
- What delegate methods should I use - if above question's answer is yes?
- [image: I have uploaded an image for the sample check it out.]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't look like standard index view is customizable.

In my application I just created custom index view instead of standard one. Basically all  you need to do here is track touch position in that view and scroll UITableView accordingly. You may also need to add some visual effects - change view's background color on touch and highlight current section title.

Comment: Hello, would you be able to provide the code for the index view you created?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Hyabusa/CMIndexBar

Use this plugin from Hyabusa.
Simple replacment for UITableView Index that allows setting of colors

```
CMIndexBar *indexBar = [[CMIndexBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-35, 10.0, 28.0, self.view.frame.size.height-20)];
[indexBar setIndexes:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G", nil]];
[self.view addSubview:indexBar];
[indexBar release];
```

Delegate

```
- (void)indexSelectionDidChange:(CMIndexBar *)IndexBar:(int)index:(NSString*)title;
```

Comment: Is it possible to add UITableViewIndexSearch icon to CMIndexBar?

Answer (score 1):

Swift version:

```
tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() //iOS7+
tableView.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() //iOS6+
tableView.sectionIndexColor = UIColor.redColor() //iOS6+
```

To customize the index view height (`UITableViewStylePlain` style only):

```
tableView.sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.tintColor = UIColor.redColor();
```

will do it for you

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is not official Apple available to do that. And Apple may reject you app if you do that. If you just wants to customize indexBar then below library may help you.

You can use custom library CollectionIndexTools by Swift(iOS 8+), which you can customize.

https://github.com/ReverseScale/CollectionIndexTools

Here's sample snippet for CollectionIndexTools

```
lazy var collectionViewIndex: CollectionViewIndex = {
        let collectionViewIndex = CollectionViewIndex()
        collectionViewIndex.indexTitles = ["c", "v", "t", "m", "n", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p", "h", "d", "c", "b", "q"]
        collectionViewIndex.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FakeCollectionViewController.selectedIndexDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        collectionViewIndex.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return collectionViewIndex
    }()
```