# Make UITableView index view larger?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a regular old UITableView with an index on the right side. I would like to make the index view larger but I do not think you can do this without hacking the API. One could iterate through the UITableView's subviews but that could be very fragile across OS versions. So does anyone know of a sanctioned way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to write your own. Have a look at [Customizing Section indexes in UITableView in iphone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643400/customizing-section-indexes-in-uitableview-in-iphone-application), same topic, answer: Do it yourself. The accepted answer provides some steps on how to do it.