# Set the width of the SectionIndex displaying on the right side of the UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can we specify the width of the frame in which SectionIndexes are displaying. I m displaying an image below will explain the condition I have.

[image: Image with UITableView sorted by Index along with it]

I want to wrap the words within the sectionIndex and it is possible when SectionIndex frame size is fixed so I want to set the width of the SectionIndex Frame as displayed on the right side.SectionIndex frame automatically resizes according to the word length within it.

I wrote the code to return the array from SectionIndexTitle as given below:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i <[keys count]; i++) {
    NSString *str = [self.keys objectAtIndex:i];
    int length = [str length];
    if (length > 9) {
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@..",[str substringToIndex:8]];
    }
       [array addObject:str];
}


NSArray *a =[NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
[array release];

return a;
```

Would u please help me regarding this...!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, customizing the section index is not possible using the public APIs.

You'll probably end up creating a custom section index view if this feature so important for your app.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this answer:

[Custom UITableView section index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987399/custom-uitableview-section-index)

I think it is really tough or next to impossible to customize section index or create custom section index.

Let me know if you need more help.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Princekumar: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: for(UIView *view in [tableView subviews])
            {
             if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewIndex"])
             {
              [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
              [view setFrame:CGRectMake(232, 0, 100, tableView.bounds.size.height)];
             }
            }   I have applied this in cellForRowAtIndexPath method and it sets background perfectly but set frame is not working . Why so?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem and I didn't have the time integrate a custom sectionindex. So I simply modified the first item in the section index list with spaces:

```
-(NSArray<NSString *> *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return @[@"      A      ", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F"];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    if ([title containsString:@"A"])
    {
        title = @"A";
    }
    //Your code here
}
```

With this solution I manged to modify the width of the section index!

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well on iPad and iPhone 5. Using it in cellForRow.

```
let rightOffset: CGFloat = cell.frame.width - cell.contentView.frame.width
```