# How to change the dimension (width, height) of an index bar in a tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

My question is quite simple and I'm surprised I couldn't find more topic related to it.

I have a tableView with an index bar on the right side. The problem is that this bar is way too thin and it's pretty hard to "click" on it. How I can change the dimensions?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987399/custom-uitableview-section-index) for customizing UITableViewIndex

From the answers found in above link and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085604/set-the-width-of-the-sectionindex-displaying-on-the-right-side-of-the-uitablevie), I found a solution for myself:

```
func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    arrOfIndex[0] = "   \(arrOfIndex[0])"
    return arrOfIndex
}
```

If you dont want the spaces, feel free to strip the spaces in `sectionForSectionIndexTitle`

Comment: Seems the white space after the index title gets trimmed

Comment: Yes, we can only provide space before the index title. I don't know why exactly