# How to change the font size of index in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, indexing

In my project i have set index using sectionIndexTitlesForTableView method. but i am not able to set the font size of the index. Can any one tell me how to set the size of it??

Comment: check this out 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45833038/4025645

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right, try following code:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UILabel *testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    testLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 8, 320, 20);
    testLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    testLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [headerView addSubview:testLabel];

    return headerView;
}
```

Comment: The code you gave is foe section header but i want code for index, Thats the list of alphabets in the right side of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I just find a great project on GitHub, highly customizable.
[MJNIndexView](https://github.com/matthewfx/MJNIndexView)
I hope it will help you.