# sectionIndexTitlesForTableView not showing proper result

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I want to fit all a-z characters but it's not showing in UITableView.I want output like below first image but I am getting output like second image.Anybody can help me to solve this issue.I put red mark on that particular area.Even I want to change text color of A-Z alphabets.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index

Comment: @NagaMalleshMaddali: Please check my question again.I already used this method but it is giving output like second image but i want output like first image.

Answer (score 1):

iOS will automatically truncate your array if it's too long.  For example, if you view your contact list in portrait orientation you will see a full index A-Z but when you rotate to landscape you'll see A * D * .... and so on.

Reduce your array to only A-Z and it will appear correctly.

If you have other items that you can't live without, remove less used letters such as 'Q', 'X', & 'Y'.  Or you can even query your table and only display the index letters from what is currently in your table but this might look odd if your missing a lot of letters.

---

If you must keep your full list and want to reduce the text size or font type, [check out this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10612117/2521004)

---

To change the color of the letters just do it the IB by selecting your table view in the story board and change the text color to your desired color.

Example: Text for index is now red

[image]

Comment: thanks very much friend :) i wasted quite a long time figuring out why my index is not showing. Turned out the text colour of tableView was automatically selected as clear colour.