# UITableView section index font family

Tags: uitableview

I know its possible to change the font color and background color for section indexes...But I was wondering If its possible to change the font family...I am trying to use icon family for certain sections.

```
tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSMutableArray *indexTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString *title in [self getAllSectonTypes]) {
        if ([title isEqualToString:@"{numeric}"]) {
            [indexTitles addObject:@"#"];
        } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"{favorites}"]) {
            // CHANGE FONT FAMILY
        } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"{mostrecent}"]) {
            // CHANGE FONT FAMILY
        } else {
            [indexTitles addObject:title];
        }
    }

    return indexTitles;
}
```

Comment: As this is for section index titles, I assume the title will be short. Have you considered looking up the unicode value using OS X Font Book, then using the unicode value within your code, or alternatively (though not recommended by many) copying and pasting the glyph into your code. For example:  ◇  "White Diamond" = U+25C7.

Comment: andrewbuilder, yes I have done this for particular sections, but I'd like to use a `clock` for most recent section

Comment: check this out 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45833038/4025645