# How to disable user interaction of section index for UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have implemented a section index, letters at the right of the table view that allow quickly jumping to a section, in my app. I would like to disable user interaction with that section index in some situations, but there is no property on `UITableView` that allows directly accessing the section index.

*How can I disable user interaction for section indexes?*

I have disabled interaction with the table itself so that you cannot scroll or tap any cell, but this still allows interacting with the section indexes, so it will scroll to each section upon tapping a section icon.

```
self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

If it's not possible to disable interaction with the section index itself, is there a way to prevent changing the scroll position of the table? That's exactly what I wanted to obtain.

Comment: you mean the index on the right side or is it the section index title

Comment: The single character buttons at the far right of the screen.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987399/custom-uitableview-section-index I will research some more

Comment: Is the section index another `UITableView`?

Comment: You could just not display it by returning `nil` in `sectionForSectionIndexTitle`.  This is what I do when I have fewer number of rows than the height of my screen and don't need the index to show.

Comment: @TengyuLiu No it's generated with the data source methods of UITableView.

Comment: @PortlandRunner That would work, but I would prefer them always be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

Keep a BOOL to know when the section indexes should be disabled.

Then in `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:` just `return -1` to prevent scrolling when tapping indexes.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    if (self.tableViewIsDisabled) {
        return -1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, if you wish to allow scrolling - so users can see what's there - but prevent them from making selections, etc. you can do the following instead:

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.tableViewIsDidabled)
        return nil;
    else
        return indexPath;
}
```

and, setting the sectionForSectionIndexTitle to nil.

Comment: Thanks. While I don't want that behavior perhaps someone else will find your answer useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UITableView *tab;
```

mm to disable scroll..

```
tab.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

if you wanna use it in certain situations.. 
you can try with a powerful..

```
if(...)
tab.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Setting `scrollEnabled` to `NO` doesn't prevent jumping to different sections with the indexes, unfortunately.