# Section Index Font for TableView

Tags: swift, xcode, indexing, tableview

Does anyone know if it’s possible to change the section index font? I know i can change the color, but, i want to change the font. My app utilizes a different language and i want the index font to reflect that.

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987399/custom-uitableview-section-index you get correct answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom UITableView section index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987399/custom-uitableview-section-index)

Comment: Use a custom view instead. You can easily manage the custom view.

Comment: check this out 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45833038/4025645