# UITableview Sections Indexing Click Event

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is there any way to get click event of the table view section indexing?

I have researched lots but not got any appropriate suggestion. 
does anyone know how to get click event action of indexing?

I want to get click event of this blue marked indexing in the below image.

[image]

Comment: So you want to get event for a click on section of a table view? Did you try creating a custom view as a section and try adding a button or something there for the click?

Comment: no, i want to get click event of indexing of tableview not sections

Comment: UITableView has a method `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` it will tell you which index path has been tapped. Is this what you are after?

Comment: @darrenallen7 i have edited my question. do you have any suggestion for that? how to achieve that?

Comment: @AhemadabbasVagh unfortunately not, the only way I could think of would be quite a hack, and probably not the most reliable method.

Comment: @darrenallen7 any suggestion for how to implement that hack type method?

Comment: @AhemadabbasVagh What do you want to do in the click event?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I have array that contain section that has starting letter any alphabets and those alphabets may be duplicate but i want to store only unique number of alphabets in my array and at last based on that index i will find that alphabet and using that alphabet char i will do my stuff.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR In sort i have array of indexing that contain duplicate value but i will remove that duplicate values from array and based on index i will find that char from my original array.

Comment: @AhemadabbasVagh Check my updated answer and the sample data. Total number of sections is 6 including 2 duplicates. sectionIndexTitles count is 4 without the duplicates. Finally when a section index title is clicked, it finds the clicked index title's position in the array and scrolls to that section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [tableView(_:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614933-tableview) method to return the appropriate section index when a index title is clicked.

```
let sectionArr = ["a","a","b","c","d","d"]
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionArr.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sectionArr[section]
}
func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return Array(Set(sectionArr))//["a","b","c","d"]
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
    if let index = sectionArr.firstIndex(where: { $0 == title }) {
        return index//0 for a, 2 for b, 3 for c, 4 for d
    }
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom view as the index view of the UITableView as shown in below reference :

[Custom UITableView section index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987399/custom-uitableview-section-index)

This is in Objective-c but I think it is a great reference as that has the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled` events and you can set the user experience with these as you would like. Also it would be very easy to add customised behaviours in this custom indexing view.

Hope this helps.