# Can't change UITableView section index list position from center to top

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to change the position of section index list of UITable view which is always in the center of the table view. I want to change the position to top. For example, I want the section index to start from top and then make its way to the bottom but can't find any resource to actually do that.

In the red box is the default position but I want the position to be in the green box. I would really appreciate if anyone can help. Any third part source would work as well. I tried finding things here and there but to no avail.

[image]

Comment: You'll have to create a custom view for indexing. Refer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987399/custom-uitableview-section-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987399/custom-uitableview-section-index)

Comment: @JeanR the solution is 10 years old and I can't understand

Comment: As a general rule, user like "consistent" interfaces across apps. That is, users are accustomed to the way section indexes look and work, so changing that is not advised. However, it's your app, and if you really want to do that, you'll need some custom code. Quick google search comes up with this, which could be a good starting point for you to either modify or write your own: https://github.com/mindz-eye/MYTableViewIndex