# Is the appearance of the section list column customizable?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UITableView that looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure what the column of section headers on the right (the thing I've circled in red) is called, but I want to customize the list so that it looks like this:

[image]

Is this possible? Does this thing even have a name? I've tried googling this but I don't even know what it's called.

**Edit:** I'm not trying to change what letters are showing up in this list - I'm trying to change the *appearance* of the column, so that it looks like my second image here.

Answer (score 0):

It is called the Section Index Titles, And there is a delegate method in UITableViewDataSource called `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:`

This returns an array for the section titles. You can easily return an array here with the letters A to Z. 
It would look like

```
-(NSArray*)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView*)tableview{
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B"...@"Y",@"Z",nil];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you've misunderstood my question. I know how to get this column of letters to show up, but I'm trying to alter their *appearance*, so that they look like the second image I posted.

Comment: Here is a link on how to do what your looking for I believe:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750119/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-side-alphabet-in-an-indexed-uitableview

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible out of the box but you could custom index view instead as suggested here:
[Customizing Section indexes in UITableView in iphone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643400/customizing-section-indexes-in-uitableview-in-iphone-application)

Or use this open source project:  https://github.com/Hyabusa/CMIndexBar

Good luck