# Subclass UITableView to change font colour of the section index?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a dark background with a `UITableView` on top of it. By default the section index is semi-transparent with a dark text colour. I'd like to change the text colour for the section index to the same colour as I have made the `UITableViewCell` title label. I have read around a bit and it seems you have to subclass the `UITableView`? How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customizing Section indexes in UITableView in iphone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643400/customizing-section-indexes-in-uitableview-in-iphone-application) I don't think its possible with the public API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I used the following in viewDidAppear:

```
for (UIView *subView in [self.view subviews])
   {
        if ([[[subView class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewIndex"])
        {
            [subView performSelector:@selector(setIndexColor:) withObject:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        }
    }
```

Since it's not documented, it has to be through a selector.

Comment: Upvoted with the caveat that using private APIs carries the risk of rejection from the App Store. I don't know how Apple's automated code review works, but you might consider replacing `@selector(setIndexColor:)` with `NSSelectorFromString(@"setIndexColor:")`. Also, using `respondsToSelector:` in the conditional would be safer than checking the class description.

Answer (score 6):

Since iOS 6 you have the possibility to do it like:

```
searchTable.sectionIndexColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 6.0 there are two methods that allow you to change the color of the section indexes and the background shown when you drag the scrubber.

```
if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSectionIndexColor:)]) {
    tableView.sectionIndexColor = ... // some color
    tableView.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = ... // some other color
}
```

Of course this will only execute if the device has 6.0+. With any older iOS, nothing will change.