# UITableView: How to remove index?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've been playing around with the tutorial [*Core Data Tutorial: How To Use NSFetchedResultsController*](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller). If I add a `sectionNameKeyPath` to the `NSFetchedREsultsController` I will get a `UITableView like this: [image]

When I provide it with a `sectionNameKayPath` it creates a index in the right side of the view. In my application the Section Titles are dates like "Sunday 11. december", "Saturday 10. december" etc. These values are not appropriate for a index like this. How can I remove the index from my ´UITableView´

Comment: Maybe this can help you? :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581606/uitableview-hide-sectionindex-but-retain-sections

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply remove the implementations of `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` and `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:` from your data source object. Without these, no index will be created.